# XPages SSJS is not started throw Reverse-Proxy

Tags: xpages, reverse-proxy, xpages-ssjs

may be someone helps :)

1. I don't know much about Apache-Reverse-Server

I have a simple X-Page, see the code bellow.

If I open the xpage via
*http: //domain1.de/e.nsf/test.xsp*
and press the button, in log.nsf i see my print-out "Button is clicked"

If I open the xpage via
*https: //example1.someproxy/rp/sproxy/http$domain1.de$80$/e.nsf/test.xsp*
and press the button, in log.nsf i **DON'T** see my print-out "Button is clicked"

The Proxy-Server is installed and configured not by me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
<xp:link escape="true" id="link1" disableTheme="true">
    <xp:image id="image1" url="/btn.jpg"></xp:image>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete" >
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:print("Button is clicked");}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:link>
```

What could be the problem, that the SSJS-code is not started via Reverse-Proxy at all?

Comment: Are there any errors thrown in Firebug related to loading resources? With IIS I know we had to redirect certain calls in addition to just .nsf.

Comment: No, there are no errors by loading resources.  What do u mean: "redirect certain calls in addition to just .nsf"?

Comment: Does the proxy server rewrite URLs in the response HTML? The XPage is going to include Ajax/POST URLs like "/e.nsf/test.xsp?..." without knowledge of the proxy prefix. So if the proxy isn't rewriting the HTML automatically, any actions you take on the page will POST to the wrong location.

Comment: Some resources, e.g. the Dojo-related script libraries including xspClientDojo.js which handles partial and full refreshes, are not within the NSF but in a URL "/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.6.1/ibm/xsp/widget/layout/layers/xspClientDojo.js". So any proxy that redirects just "*.nsf" will display the page fine but be missing theme images and button clicks will not work.

Comment: Yes, Reverse-Proxy rewrite URLs and image-paths (if I add), js-paths, but they are shown OK. As I saw in firebug console, the button is clicked in the browser, the POST is sent to the server (without error in firebug), but it looks like, server does not start the server-action.

Comment: Is the response from the POST request what you would expect? It's a useful way to identify whether the partial refresh has hit an error, for example incorrect page or some other fatal error. Even today I've had a situation where a partial refresh resulted in an Error 500, which explained the cause of why my partial refresh wasn't working.

Comment: Is the path in the HTTP POST correct?

Answer (score 0):

Is reverse proxy the problem? Or is the problem that your code is not triggering?

I can't tell from your user id how experienced with XPages you are, but bear in mind a number of steps are performed on the server before it gets to your print statement. One of the key ones is conversion and validation. So if anything on your XPage throws a validation error, it won't run SSJS code.

Do you have a Display Errors control on the XPage and, more importantly, inside the refresh area? If not, add one. We've all spent hours in our early XPages life because validation or data conversion has failed and we didn't add anything to let us know. Once you get more confident, a PhaseListener is another useful tool for checking any or all lifecycle phases are running.

Comment: Hi Paul, thx for feedback, pls see the code upper. 
What I'v done:    
   1. I created new database.     
   2. I created a simple X-Page (No Validation or Data Conversion).    
   .
About Display Errors - the code is so simple ;)    
    
P.S. Experience with XPages is more thän 2 years.